# AJAX code returns error of "Column cannot be null" for PHP Session variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm trying to insert some variables to my database with AJAX but I get this error message:

```
Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'chname' cannot be null in clubviewhand.php:20
```

I don't get how I'm getting this error message. I clearly defined `chname` variable in my AJAX code so it shouldn't be null. I would greatly appreciate some help with this, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot & before sname in ajax request.

replace

```
 xmlhttp.open('GET','clubviewhand.php?cbid='+chcbid+'sname='+chname+'&chpost='+chpost,true);
```

with

```
 xmlhttp.open('GET','clubviewhand.php?cbid='+chcbid+'&sname='+chname+'&chpost='+chpost,true);
```

Comment: Wth.. why did StackOverflow delete my comment for? So now I can't thank people for correcting my mistake? Wtf. Anyways, thanks again - so ridiculous of me to miss that, you have a keen eye!

Comment: Your welcome.I was very happy that I was able to solve your problem